# How to achieve this in a matrix report in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

i am developing a report using SSRS matrix control.

Here is a sample table with which i am working with

[image: funmix]

and here is what I am trying to achieve using a matrix tool in SSRS

[image: Results]

oK the description now

the report needs to pic the type A,B,C and its case amount grouping it by location code. the 6th row will contain a calculated value of derived from the row 4 and 5 (type A and type B).

As it is shown int the screenshot the formula used to derive the result ($44) is by using the formula

```
(Case Value of Type B * average of Type B) + (Case Value of Type C * average of Type C)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           (Case Value of Type B + Case Value of Type C)
```

so the value of $44 can be achieved as

```
(57 * 18) + (44 * 78) / (57 + 44)
```

can someone pleas guide me how can i implement this in ssrs. 
I have made the structure but unable to calculate the total value.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you get your averages.  Is this happening behind the scenes with something you predetermine or are you doing it based on other tables you can join to?

I would do this if it is all in datasets you can get:

1. Determine a dataset that is both your data and your averages.  I am unsure if you are originating from SQL or just doing this all in Excel.  I will dummy in SQL for the time being:

   ```
   declare @Avgs Table ( location int, type varchar(1), cs int, average int);

   insert into @Avgs values (1, 'A', 21, 10),(1, 'B', 57, 18),(1, 'C', 44, 78);

   Select top 10 *
   from @Avgs
   ```
2. You probably want to add a 'computed column' or do the math directly in SQL as the expression editor in SSRS is generally okay for things that are a function or two but when you have very involved math I find the SQL engine better for handling it.  This also makes it better later to change things out.
3. So I would amend the SQL as such:

   ```
   declare @Avgs Table ( location int, type varchar(1), cs int, average int);

   insert into @Avgs values (1, 'A', 21, 10),(1, 'B', 57, 18),(1, 'C', 44, 78);

   With a as 
        (
        select *, cs * average as compound
        from @Avgs
        )
    , b as 
        (
        Select 
            (max( case when type = 'B' then compound end) +    max( case when type = 'C' then compound end)) /
            (max( case when type = 'B' then cs end) + max( case when type = 'C' then cs end))  as CompoundMath
        from a
       )
   select *
   from a, b
   ```
4. This would be your dataset in SSRS, the compound function can be changed as such inside the (case when ... end)  after the 'when' is the logic, after the 'then' is what results.
5. Simply add a new row and you get your custom expression set as the column called 'Compound Math'.